# SQL value at min query without join

Tags: sql, join, min

Quite often I have to solve the following problem. Suppose I have 3 columns: Col A, Col B, Col C.

Col A contain some date which I need group on. Col B contains value for which I need to find minimum for each group in Col A. And Col C contains data for which I would like to find where minimum occurred, that is pull value from Col C corresponding to min in Col B.

I commonly solve this problem, but writing JOIN statement. Does anybody know better solution, without JOIN? The problem seem so common to me that I would image it would make sense to create dedicated SQL command. It is like finding value of the function at a point of minimum (from math point of view)

Regards,

UPDATE.

I apologize for not posting an example of what I mean. Here is my table:

```
Location            Quantity    Street
New York            2            Broad
New York            3            Main
Pittsburgh          1            Grove
Pittsburgh          5            School
Austin              7            Hayes
Austin              2            Barn
```

I would like to group by "Location" and choose min in "Quantity" for each group. Finally I would like to find "Street" corresponding to each min value.

Here is how my final output should look like:

```
 Location           Quantity    Street
 Austin             2           Barn
 New York           2           Broad
 Pittsburgh         1           Grove
```

And here is how I accomplish it ( I believe it is too long and there should be dedicated SQL function for it)

```
SELECT TheFunction.Location, Quantity, Street  
FROM [AnalysisDatabase].[dbo].[ValueAtMin] As TheFunction

inner join 

(SELECT [Location], Min([Quantity]) as MinValue
FROM [AnalysisDatabase].[dbo].[ValueAtMin] Group by [Location]) as XValue

on TheFunction.Location = XValue.Location and XValue.MinValue = TheFunction.Quantity
```

Comment: can you post an example code of what you are doing today, in addition to your description?  Usually there is a `min` type of function, but your question seems to be about how to avoid using `join`?

Answer (score 1):

This works with your dataset in mysql:

```
select location, quantity, street
  from tempso c
where quantity = (select min(quantity)
  from tempso b
  where c.location = b.location)
order by location
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this sql below:

Data table (using @temp)

```
location                       quantity    Street
------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
New York                       2           Broad
New York                       3           Main
Pittsburgh                     1           Grove
Pittsburgh                     5           School
Austin                         7           Hayes
Austin                         2           Barn
```

SQL:

```
select location, quantity, street from @temp a
where quantity in (select min(quantity) as quantity from @temp b group by location having a.location = b.location)
order by location asc, quantity desc
```

Data Result:

```
location                       quantity    street
------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
Austin                         2           Barn
New York                       2           Broad
Pittsburgh                     1           Grove
```

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql:

```
select
distinct on (a)
a,b,c
from tbl
order by a, b
```

You can also achieve it with a window function to figure out the correct c,
and then group by a (by putting the window query inside the grouping query)